# What is the most efficient way to get the count of a Object list in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I have a list and a Object as bellow

```
List<MyObj> myList;

public class MyObjextends
{
   String parameter1;

    public String getParameter1()
    {
        return parameter1;
    }
}
```

I need an efficient way to get the count of myList based on the value of parameter1 in the object without going through a for loop as bellow

```
    int count = 0;
    for( MyObj obj: myList)
    {
        if( obj.getParameter1().equals( "Somet_Text") )
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Enlighten us with the reason you do not want to use a `for` loop.

Comment: Without using a hash table (or the Java Equivalent, it's been a while), you won't be able to do a direct index lookup against a property of an item; you'll need to loop through the list to see if that item is in there. So to do a count of items that match a specific criteria, you'll have to loop through the list.

Comment: you cant, you could wrap your loop in some generic util function, but you cant get rid off it

Comment: No, it seems that OP wants to count only objects that match his/her criteria (see `obj.getParameter`().equals()`

Answer (score 0):

Use a Map from parameter1 to List of MyObj and then you can use the size of `map.get("Some_Text")`

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the list up in a class which also has a `HashMap<String, List<MyObj>>`.  Only allow access to the list via methods which also control the hash map.  Whenever an item is added to the list, it should also be added to the hash map.

Answer (score 0):

if stay with `List` structure, you have to do it with loop. if you don't do it, the api you used will do it any way.

If this is the main problem you want to solve, you can consider to use `MultiMap` Structure. Like guava's `ListMultimap<String, MyObj>`.

In fact it is something like `map<String, List<MyObj>>`

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you would not use a for loop to iterate List, Even if efficiency is a consideration, it would not matter at all practically. But even then if you have something against `for`, use the iterator for list

```
ListIterator<MyObj> it=myList.listIterator();
int count = 0;

    while(it.hasNext()){

if( it.next().getParameter1().equals( "Somet_Text") )
        {
            count++;
        }
}
```

Also looking at the source for ListIterator.next() , it does not use for loop too, just if it makes any difference

```
public E More ...next() {
            checkForComodification();
            int i = cursor;
            if (i >= size)
                 throw new NoSuchElementException();
             Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
            if (i >= elementData.length)
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
             cursor = i + 1;
             return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
     }
```

But note that it uses if statement and increments cursor to traverse the list, which again would be something like a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a real reason to not wanting search in a ordered array as interface List is with a loop. The big O notation of this loop would be O(N) which is exactly what is pretended to be.

If you have to process data from a huge array of inputs, I would recommend pre-process the information by discarding the objects with the values you don't want and create the array with the values that you really need.

The Map solutions commented won't solve your problem neither, as one rule of construction is that no repeated values are allowed, which is exactly what you want to measure.